# Session variables won't set using IronRouter and Meteor to dynamically set values

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In my Meteor application I am using IronRouter to dynamically generate a session variable so as part "after" block when loading my router. Unfortunately, the Session variables are not generated and the dynamic values for the pageTitle and Subtitles are not loaded. Strangely, however, it does work when manually setting the Session vars from the browser console.

Here is my Router code:

```
this.route('dashboard'), {
    path: '/dashboard',
    after: function () {
        Session.set('pageTitle', 'Dashboard');
        Session.set('pageSubTitle', 'Welcome to your dashboard.');
    }
};
```

I've also tried this ina before block, too.

Here's the helper function:

```
// Set title and subtitle values
Template.pageSetup.helpers({
pageTitle: function() {
    return Session.get('pageTitle');
},

pageSubTitle: function() {
    return Session.get('pageSubTitle');
}
```

});

Here's the block from my template that renders:

```
      <h3 class="title">
        <i class="icon-dashboard"></i>
        {{pageTitle}}
      </h3>
      <h5>
        <span>
          {{pageSubTitle}}
        </span>
      </h5>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: worked perfectly for me, try looking for other errors that might cause a problem. i would suggest to provide a the pageTitle and subTitle as the data context in the route like so: data:{pageTitle:"Dashboard",pageSubTitle:"Welcome to your dashboard."} unless you really need them to be reactive with session. [good article about overuse of session](http://projectricochet.com/blog/meteor-js-performance#.UvFXqR8Q-Y4)

Comment: FYI: The `after:` action is deprecated and is now called `onAfterAction:`.